# How to save video to Laravel storage folder on Tinymce

Tags: laravel, tinymce-5

I'd like to save the video I uploaded in the Laravel storage folder, but for now I'm only able to save this away:

```
 <p><video controls="controls" width="300" height="150">
<source src="data:video/mp4;base64,AAAAIGZ0eXBpc29tAAACAGl</video></p>
```

I would like the url to be

> `storage/video-name

.
My current code is this:

```
file_picker_types: 'media',
            file_picker_callback: function(cb, value, meta) {
                var input = document.createElement('input');

                input.setAttribute('type', 'file');

                input.onchange = function() {
                var file = this.files[0];

                var reader = new FileReader();
                
                reader.onload = function () {
                    var id = 'blobid' + (new Date()).getTime();
                    var blobCache =  tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
                    var base64 = reader.result.split(',')[1];
                    var blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file, base64);

                    blobCache.add(blobInfo);

                    cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), { title: file.name }); // here
            };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            };
                
                input.click(); //here
        },
```

How could I adapt my code so that I can save it in Laravel storage folder?

Laravel version: 8
Tinymce: 5